# Apply sealant in or to the designated locations?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'am trying to translate technical document. Which of the sentences below is correct?

- Apply sealant in the designated locations/areas
- Apply sealant to the designated locations/areas
  The designated locations are the locations on a part which are specified in the drawing.

In addition to the above, is the sentence below understandable?

- The worker mistakenly placed a product that already has been finished applying sealant
- The worker mistakenly placed a product that already has gone through the sealant application process
  (The one applying sealant is a robot.)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are asking the difference between 'area' and 'location'.

The word 'area' can be used differently in certain contexts. In mathematics, an area is something that can be calculated, such as the square dimensions of a surface. However, we use the word much more loosely to refer to any space around a fixed point - for example, "*in my area*" might refer to a region around which you live. It could be your whole town, or a locale, or just specific parts of those places closest to you - it is not a requirement to be so specific in this context unless it affects what you are saying.

By contrast, 'location' is always something *specific* - something that can be *located* by specific direction, such as coordinates or a simple description.

I imagine that 'applying sealant' is something done to an extended area, rather than a fixed point. For example, the 4 corners of a window might be referred to as 'locations', but the edge between two corners might better be called an 'area'.

As for your sentences - no, they aren't clear, but proofreading is off-topic here, and a question should be focused on one point, so forgive me for just answering your main, on-topic point.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I should use "area" since the document suggests applying sealant to the edge of a part.

Answer (score 0):

*Apply sealant to* is fine.  *Apply sealant in* is not appropriate as *in* usually refers, for example, to a room.  It may be read as referring to the room or space the work is to be carried out.

> Apply sealant *to* the designated **parts**.

would be better as *locations/areas* typically refer to large areas.

Your point 3 does not sound natural; point 4 is fine.

Your can consider also

> The worker mistakenly placed a product that has already undergone its sealant application.

> The worker mistakenly placed a product that already has its sealant application done.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I suppose to apply sealant in the shape of a line, is it still better to use the word "part"?   e.g. Sealant applied on vehicle parts

Comment: We may say "Apply sealant on the vehicle parts following the lines as shown in the drawing."  "Apply sealant on" seems to sound better than "apply sealant to".

Comment: Thank you. In this context, is following the lines means you create lines that are same as the lines shown on the drawing?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: ok! Thank you  very much!